# How to add third party jar to mapreduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

Looking for the solution to add third party jar into mapreduce job. Currently, we are bundling third-party jar into map reduce job. Seems sometimes size of mapreduce job jar is going to high. is there another approach to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally going down the uber jar route is the is a good one, adding jars to the generic java classpath becomes problematic in the event you have dependencies on a different version of the same jar for different MapReduce jobs.

Comment: Generally going down the uber jar route is the is a good one - what does  it mean.. can you please elaborate more

Comment: you pack all your dependency jars in the jar you build to run your application. (this is a much better explanation than I could give https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947037/what-is-an-uber-jar )

Answer (score 1):

I believe "-libjars jar1,jar2,..." is what you need here

Comment: @LearnHadoop it is an option of hadoop command. Like this: "hadoop jar mapreduce.jar -libjars <additional_jars>"

Answer (score 0):

Use the below sentence.

> export
>   HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/path/to/my/jar1:/path/to/my/jar2

Then you can run your hadoop jobs as usual: `hadoop jar [mainClass]`. For more details check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27731065/adding-jars-to-the-classpath-of-the-code-that-launches-map-reduce-job).

Comment: thanks .. if you could add in CLASSPATH may be it will come version issue..